# How can I make an array of some words of HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="tags_autoloaderBox">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>PHP</span>
      <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>HTML</span>
      <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>CSS</span>
      <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>MySQL</span>
      <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I need to make a array of all those tag names. Something like this:

```
var arr = ['PHP','HTML','CSS','MySQL'];
```

So I need to parse the HTML. Is doing that possible by either JS or jQuery?

Comment: Just, by the way.... Are you sure you want/need those extra `div` elements that contain the `div` elements that contain the `span` elements?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes I'm  sure `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.from()`, object destructuring to return `textContent` property of `span` `DOM` element

```js
let res = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".tags_autoloaderBox span"), ({textContent}) => textContent);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<div class="tags_autoloaderBox">
    <div><div>
        <span>PHP</span>
        <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div></div>
    <div><div>
        <span>HTML</span>
        <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div></div>
    <div><div>
        <span>CSS</span>
        <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div></div>
    <div><div>
        <span>MySQL</span>
        <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MartinAJ `console.log(res.join(" | "))`. Though note, _"how can I make an string of those names by a separator?"_ does not appear at original Question as a requirement. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `res.join(" | ");`

Answer (score 2):

This jquery should work to get the array:

```
var array = $(".tags_autoloaderBox span").map(function (){
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

To convert that to a delimited string, you could do this:

```
var str = array.join(" | ");
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Ln9o38y/)

[jQuery map documentation](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

[MDN array join documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Why would you need `.get()` there? Just curious.

Comment: `map` returns a jQuery object, `get` transforms it into an array

Comment: $.map will return you an array, while $.fn.map returns an object.  So if you wanted to avoid the get() you could use the first one.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. just for my information, how can I make an string of those names by a separator? Something like this? `PHP | HTML | CSS | MySQL`

Comment: you could then do `array.join(' | ');` to convert it to a delimited string, updated answer to include

Answer (score 2):

Here's a straight JavaScript solution that gathers up the `<span>` elements, loops through them and puts their text content into an array:

```js
// Create an empty array to hold the results:
var results = [];

// Gather all the relevant span elements and loop through them:
document.querySelectorAll(".tags_autoloaderBox span").forEach(function(element){
  // Push each element's text content into the array
  results.push(element.textContent);
});
// Output as needed:
console.log(results.join(" | "));
```

```html
<div class="tags_autoloaderBox">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>PHP</span>
      <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>HTML</span>
      <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>CSS</span>
      <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>MySQL</span>
      <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to be on a safer side, I would change the selector to `.tags_autoloaderBox span`

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. just for my information, how can I make an string of those names by a separator? Something like this? `PHP | HTML | CSS | MySQL`

Comment: @ScottMarcus Note, _"how can I make an string of those names by a separator?"_ does not appear at text of original Question as requirement.

Comment: @guest271314 My answer of how to make the array hasn't changed and so it is still perfectly valid.  The addition of the `.join()` to the answer is incidental.

Answer (score 2):

Using querySelectorAll you can select all the spans within the div and just create an array and push these span contents into it

check this snippet

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.tags_autoloaderBox');
var spans = div.querySelectorAll('span');
var arr = [];
var str="";
spans.forEach(function(span) {
  arr.push(span.innerHTML);
});
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.join("| "));
```

```html
<div class="tags_autoloaderBox">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>PHP</span>
      <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>HTML</span>
      <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>CSS</span>
      <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>MySQL</span>
      <p>there is some explanations</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Exactly the same as my answer.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. just for my information, how can I make an string of those names by a separator? Something like this? `PHP | HTML | CSS | MySQL`

Comment: you can event do it by using arr.join("|")...modified the code snippet

Comment: @Geeky What is purpose of `var str=""`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like it is already answered, but I wrote it out and thought I would share. This will work if your browser does not support querySelectorAll...

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var arr = getSpanTagsArr;
        // Do whatever you want with the arr here.
    });
    function getSpanTagsArr() {
        var tagHolders = document.getElementsByClassName('tags_autoloaderBox');
        var tags = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < tagHolders.length; i++) {
            var spans = tagHolders[i].getElementsByTagName('span');
            for (var j = 0; j < spans.length; j++) {
                var tag;
                if (spans[i].textContent) {
                    val = spans[j].textContent;
                }
                else if (spans[j].innerText) {
                    val = spans[j].innerText;
                }
                else {
                    val = spans[j].innerHTML;
                }
                if (tags.indexOf(val) == -1) {
                    tags.push(val);
                }
            }
        }
        return tags;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but if your browser doesn't support `querySelectorAll()` it must be 2006! And, if it doesn't support `querySelectorAll()`, it's not going to support `getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: I mainly just posted it because I already had it typed out. I did think that querySelectorAll() support was lagging behind querySelector() in IE for a while. I forget these things.